# How to give from's name/id in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to submit the form to the controller.

My code:

```
<% form_tag(:controller=>"a", :action=>"b", :method=>"c") do %>
```

which converts the view like this:

```
<form action="/a/b?method=c" method="post">
...
</form>
```

But i want view... like this...

```
<form name="myFormName" id="myFromId" action="/a/b?method=c" method="post">
...
</form>
```

I have checked this official link: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html
but i cant find solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this kind of information via:

```
<% form_tag({ :controller=>"a", :action=>"b", :method=>"c" }, { :name => "myFromName", :id => "myFromId" }) do %>
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response... I have already tried for that...but it renders view like this... <form action="/a/b/myFromId?method=c&name=myFromName" method="post">

Comment: yeah... i read somewhere before some time about this property... but it was out of my mind... :) thanks buddy.

Answer (score 1):

```
form_for {:controller=>"a", :action=>"b", :method=>"c" }, :html => { :name => "myFormName", :method => "post", :id => "myFromId" }
```

Comment: it is ok. solving your problem is the most important thing.